# jQuery 1.9 Issue with multiline html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, replace

I'm having a little issue updating from jQuery 1.7.3 to jQuery 1.9.0:

http://jsfiddle.net/xsJAd/

It seems it doesn't like to accept multiline html.  If you uncomment the first couple lines you will see the error in the console.  Was this done on purpose in 1.9 or is this a bug, I really don't want to be putting `.replace()` calls all over my code.

Comment: Just an update, works fine in 1.8.3, it's only 1.9.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to trim the whitespace from the start of the `html()` for this to work:

```
console.log($($.trim($('#tpl-tableList').html())));
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/xsJAd/1/)

Comment: Well, that's just as annoying.

Comment: Yeah, it's not pretty. I've had similar issues when returning HTML back from a JSON request which had a <kbd>tab</kbd> or other whitespace as the first character.

Comment: Okay, well seems to be the best answer so far, so I'll just go with that, thanks.